# How to run a .bat file as administrator automatically each time when I start a specific program?

Tags: windows-7, services, administrator, batch-file

In order to speed up my computer start time I disable the VM services in startup; and those services are mandatory for me to start the VMware Workstation when I need to use it.

So I wrote a simple batch file which tells windows to start those services; but it is quite inconvenient for me to right click the batch file and choose "run as administrator" each time before I'm about to start the VMware Workstation.

So is there a trick to run the batch file as administrator automatically each time when I click the VMware Workstation icon? To be clear, each time when I click the Workstation icon it will run the batch file first and after the batch file is done then the VM will start.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to you could disable the prompt altogether which is what I do. This can be done by typing `UAC` in the Start menu search bar and changing the setting to never notify.

Alternatively you can do this: [Make Vista launch UAC restricted programs at startup with Task Scheduler | TechRepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/make-vista-launch-uac-restricted-programs-at-startup-with-task-scheduler/616)

Comment: Thanks! lately I just make my .bat file to also START the program as well.